# Is it possible to POST a string/byte array as a file without writing a file?

Tags: java, file, post, multipartform-data

I have a string that is a base64 encoded gzipped png that is a response from a web service (It's a shipping label). I can easily save it to a file and then `POST` the file to the endpoint. However, it would seem more practical if I can just somehow attach the png to the request and *send it as a file* instead of having to save and upload it.

The 3rd party endpoint is expecting a file upload like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary6Pa1wvNhXthHAKpp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="scaled.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundary6Pa1wvNhXthHAKpp--
```

I know I can save the file and then post the file

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addPart("name", new FileBody(name));
String response = Request.Post(end).body(builder.build())
                    .execute().returnContent().toString();
```

Is there a way to get the same result without saving the png to the file system?

Comment: You're then keeping the image in memory, but what happens when you run low?  How would you deal with a corrupt or partially transmitted image in the event of a network blackout?  Why do you want to avoid writing the file to disk?

Comment: @Makoto This seems to be fetching a resource from one web service, processing it, then posting to another web service. Why would one want to bother with writing it to disk? If you're low on memory it won't be discarded because it's strongly reachable. If the network goes down you would restart the operation by re-fetching the original resource. Only if the _processing_ step were costly in time and/or CPU would it make sense to write the intermediate file to disk, because writing to disk is itself costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [ByteArrayBody](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ByteArrayBody.html) which implements `AbstractContentBody`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it to the remote server in the exact same format you can always get the best of both worlds...

```
//Or however you get your response from the remote server
InputStream postalImageData = serverResponse.getEntity().getContent();
//...
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody("name", postalImageData);
//...
```

This approach wouldn't necessarily pull the entire file into memory at all, it would simply stream it from one server to the other.

If you want to decompress it (but not do anything else) you could use a GZIPInputStream and accomplish the same result.

If you need to manipulate the entity then you have no choice but to pull it into memory (unless you can do the manipulation in a streaming fashion).